# Micronaut jdbcOperations not injected to repository

Tags: jdbc, jdbctemplate, micronaut

I am following a guide on Micronaut docs on how to setup a JDBC repository and for some reason I can't get it to work. I added a sample code of what I am doing.

Repository:

```
@JdbcRepository(dialect = Dialect.POSTGRES)
abstract class PersonRepository implements CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

    private JdbcOperations jdbcOperations;

    PersonRepository(JdbcOperations jdbcOperations) {
        this.jdbcOperations = jdbcOperations
    }

    @Transactional
    List<Person> search() {
        String sql = "select * from person";
        return jdbcOperations.prepareStatement(sql, statement -> {
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
            return jdbcOperations.entityStream(resultSet, Person.class).collect(Collectors.toList());
        });
    }
```

application.yml:

```
datasources:
  default:
   url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:8001/postgres
   driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
   username: postgres
   password: 'postgres'
   dialect: POSTGRES
   logsql: true


jpa:
  default:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: update
```

dependencies for the application

dependencies {

```
compileOnly "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
implementation("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa")
implementation("io.micronaut.groovy:micronaut-runtime-groovy")
implementation("io.micronaut.liquibase:micronaut-liquibase")
implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-jdbc-hikari")
implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api")
implementation group: 'com.vladmihalcea', name: 'hibernate-types-52', version: '2.10.4'
implementation group: 'io.micronaut.security', name: 'micronaut-security', version: '2.4.0'
implementation group: 'io.micronaut.security', name: 'micronaut-security-jwt', version: '2.4.0'
implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.6'
implementation("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-jdbc")

compileOnly("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-processor")
testImplementation("org.testcontainers:postgresql")
testImplementation("org.testcontainers:spock")
testImplementation("org.testcontainers:testcontainers")
implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")

testAnnotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"

annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation"
compileOnly("jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:2.2.2")
```

}

Error:

```
 Unexpected error occurred: No such property: jdbcOperations for class: com.example.repositories.PersonRepository
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you use micronaut data jdbc or micronaut data jpa? Please show your gradle/maven dependencies

Comment: I added my dependancies to the question

Comment: You have jpa.. In that case it's easier use the criteria api and inject the entitymanager

Comment: Have a look at that for some examples https://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-data-access-jpa-hibernate/guide/index.html#repository

Comment: I tried using EntityManager but because I'm using database specific operators, it will not work.

Comment: Micronaut has two ways of accessing data jdbc or jpa. You could not mix them. Either jdbc operator and jdbc or entity manager and jpa... Even if jpa works with jdbc under the hood but micronaut handles that diffently